# Why doesn't Network Manager use system network scheme?

Tags: networking, network-manager, pppoe

Does anybody knows why Ubuntu's NM does'n use native implementations for networking ?

For example if I set up a pppoe connection in the network manager (using nm-applet) it has it's own way of storing connections and doesn't use native debian networking sheme, for PPPoE use pppd and store settings in `/etc/ppp/pears`. I once configured a wired connection that didn's show up in `/etc/network/interfaces` but was visible in NM ... This is BAD for me because if I don't start X, from CLI I cannot connect to my network connections configured in NM ( or not as easy I would expect), for example in CLI I could do pon "dsl-provider" or poff to turn on or off pppoe connection, but my NM's pppoe connections are not visible to pppd and if I configure a pppoe connection using pppd is not visible in NM.

Maybe I am missing something and don't know how to use it ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that there are issues with NM handling PPPoE connections, especially if through Wi-Fi.

However, to fix exactly what you're describing, you may want to try setting NetworkManager in "managed" mode by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf` and changing `managed=true` to **false**.

This tells NM to use the configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` if possible (and if it understands the syntax in there, but the logic is getting better and better) and to create a connection that can be turned on or off. It's definitely worth a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/nmcli.1.html) from the commandline to up/down a PPPoE connection registered in NM.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that, but I realy don't understand why there are 2 independent networking systems. Why is NM better then native Debian network ? Something must be better beacause Canonical doesn't do a GUI for native Debian networking doesn't it ?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea *why* it's like this, but remember that it's also still possible to configure ethernet/wifi networking "the old Debian way".

Comment: NM allows better flexibility because it adapts to changes, such as in Wi-Fi network, to state only the obvious. Configuration is also much easier for new people since they don't have to edit text files.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have to agree with the basic point here, having just spent a couple of days tracking down why I suddenly lost networking...

(This page really helped that, so thanks to all who contributed to it.)

The point being that when a 'new' way is introduced, or there are multiple configuration systems it is good to be able to connect the new way and old way and make it

a) **obvious which system is in use** (to users of the old and new systems),

b) **make it discoverable** (including the commands and apps that are recommended e.g. the nmcli reference above), and

c) that the chosen method should be **able to be managed from both the GUI and the command line**.

Thanks.